# Jquery cycle - slideshow with different speed transitions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I’m trying to make a fade slideshow with different speed values for the transition effect.

I don't want to change the Timeout, or the Fx…I just want to change the speed transition value for each image...It is possible?

Thank you very much in advance!!!

This is the code:

```
$('#s1').cycle({
    fx:     'fade',
    speed:  1000, //this is that I want to change for each img!!!
    timeout: 1700,
    next:   '#s1', 
});

<div id="s1" class="pics">
    <img src="img.jpg" width="450" height="300" />
    <img src="img.jpg" width="450" height="300" />
    <img src="img.jpg" width="450" height="300" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following property to declare per slide delays:

```
timeoutFn: function (a) { return $(a).data('delay') * 1000; },
/.../
```

which reads the "delay" data attribute from the slide.

I.e. your image tags needs to be decorated in the following manner:

```
<div id="s1" class="pics">
    <img src="img.jpg" width="450" height="300" data-delay="1" />
    <img src="img.jpg" width="450" height="300" data-delay="2" />
    <img src="img.jpg" width="450" height="300" data-delay="3" />
</div>
```

EDIT:
I read your question too quickly. I realize now you did not want to change the delay between transitions - but rather the speed of the transition.

I have not done that myself, but one approach that might work is using the event "before" in the following manner:

```
$('#s1').cycle({
    fx:     'fade',
    speed:  1000, //this is that I want to change for each img!!!
    timeout: 1700,
    next:   '#s1',
    before: function(e1, e2, opts) { opts.speed = parseInt($(e1).data('speed')); }
});
```

Comment: Thanks!

Sorry but I wrote your code but it doesn’t work…may be I wrote something wrong!

Now, I have something like that. Is it correct? 


    $('#s1').cycle({
        fx:     'fade',
        timeout: 1700,
        next:   '#s1',
  before: function(e1, e2, opts) { opts.speed = parseInt($(e1).data('speed')); }
    });

 <div id="s1" class="pics">
  <img src="img.jpg" width="450" height="300" data-speed="5000" />
  <img src="img.jpg" width="450" height="300" data-speed="1000" />
 </div>